# Project with mixed languages in .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-3.5

I’m not sure if what I am trying to do is possible, but surprisingly VS2008 seems to let me copy a .cs file directly into my VB.NET project.  I then thought that I may be able to use the class in this file directly from VB.NET.  However, it doesn’t see it when I try to reference it in.  Is what I'm trying to do possible, or is VS2008 simply treating the C# file as a resource file or something?

Comment: You can add *any* file to a project.  Yes, embedding them as a resource or copying them to the output directory is about all you can do with them.  The copy operation can be quite useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should reference CS project that contains your class written in C# from your VB project. This class should be public. After doing it, you will be able to use this class in your VB project.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to add a C# project to the solution, rather than just copying the source file. Just create a new project making sure you select it as a C# class library or similar and make sure you add it to the current solution and then copy the source file into that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want the c# code translated into vb, then be sure to have a look at 
http://converter.telerik.com/
there are many code converter but is the best I know.

Comment: +1 good link, been using [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) for c# <-> vb.net conversions, this looks good for quick conversions